# C sockets: Echo server bad reply

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I've read as many questions as I've found, still I have my problem....

I have a very sample client/server socket:

- Connection stablished between server and client **DONE**
- Receive message from client **DONE**
- Print the message in the server side **DONE**
- Send message back from server to client **PROBLEMS**
- Print the server reply in the client side **PROBLEMS**

I send the message from client to server without problems, but when I send back the message I'm allways getting weird characters

**Note: I'm adding the '\0' character to the received string**

## Client code

```
//... socket initialization and other code
write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));    
printf("Message sent ! \n"); 

// Listen for reply
listen(sockfd, 5);
struct_size = sizeof(con_addr);
serverfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&con_addr, &struct_size);

// Read message
bytes_read = read(serverfd, server_reply, 100);
server_reply[bytes_read] = '\0';
printf("Server response: %s \n", server_reply);

// Close socket
close(sockfd);
close(serverfd);
printf("Socket closed ! \n");
```

## Server Code

```
//... socket initialization, bind and other code
struct_size = sizeof(con_addr);
if( (clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&con_addr, &struct_size)) < 0 ){
    perror("Could not accept connection. Error: ");
    return 1;
}

// Read message
bytes_read = read(clientfd, client_message, 100);
client_message[bytes_read] = '\0';

printf("Message received: %s \n", client_message);      
// Send message back
n = write(clientfd, client_message , strlen(client_message));
```

I'm getting things like this:

```
Server response: �V��i�8�y�
Server response: ��ƿi�8�{�
```

Comment: Why are both sides calling `accept()`? Either my (not recently used) knowledge of socket code is forgetting something, or this is not right. My recollection is that only the server will ever call `accept()`. Further, `listen()` is not used to "listen for a reply". It's used to listen for incoming clients (required before calling `accept()`). I think it's likely that your lack of error checking the return from your calls is biting you in the nether regions.

Comment: Your code has no error checking in critical functions. If `bytes_read` is -1, for example, your code will do insane things. You don't check `listen`, `accept`, `read`, or `write` for errors in the code shown. How can you possibly hope to figure out where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confused on how TCP sockets work:

- Servers usually call [`socket(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), [`bind(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html), [`listen(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html), [`accept(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) to setup its **listening** socket.
- Clients call [`socket(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and then [`connect(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) to connect to a server.
- Once server successfully returns from [`accept(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) you have a **bi-directional byte pipe** between client and the server.

It looks like currently you are attempting to connect/accept on both sides.

Other notes:

- Always check return values of system calls - `-1` is an indication of an error, then inspect [`errno(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) for the actual problem ([`strerror(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) is useful here).
- Do not assume the data is ASCII, so not use [`strlen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) on socket input, use return value of [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

Comment: Fixed, I mixed some answers now It's clear ! I removed the listen and accept part on the client, and use same socket to send and receive messages. Thanks

Comment: @Liαrεz be sure you add in inspection of the return values. Proper error checking will keep you safe, and better alert to you problems like this.